# What can I do with "unspent" transactions? Can I transmit them to a chain?

Tags: blockchain.info, private-key, transaction-verification, listunspent

I withdrew some bitcoin from a service's account I maintain. The [transaction](https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/transaction/c0791efbbea694647fa90e0af2553b4484607c36c7f8f383360fa72fcd320067) shows up in my wallet, but it has been marked as "unspent" ever since. What does this mean?

Comment: Hi Alma,
It's not clear what your question is. Could you please edit your post to provide more context and then flag for reopening?

Comment: sorry I'm here my first transaction. I had a withdraw from a poker site and my transaction went to blockchain.com/ as unspent it been two weeks and bitcoin in my chain or wallet. thanks

Comment: I edited your question to add the context and provided an answer. I hope that I captured your concern accurately. Otherwise, please edit your question post to further specify what you want to know.

Answer (score 3):

When someone sends you bitcoins, they do so by submitting a Bitcoin transaction to the network. Transactions specify which coins they spend in the inputs, and allocate the funds to new owners on the output side. You received one such transaction output. While the other output got used already, your output is still marked as "unspent". "Unspent" in this context means "not spent yet" in the sense that it is still available to be spent. When you want to spend your bitcoins, you can use your wallet to create a transaction to send some or all of them to another Bitcoin address.